# Razor view (MVC .NET 4.0) and Microsoft.IdentityModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif

I have met the problem with ASP.NET MVC Razor wiews using classes/interfaces from Microsoft.IdentityModel namespace complaining both in design and runtime mode as below:

"The type or namespace name 'IdentityModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' 
   (are   you missing an assembly reference?)"

same seems to appear in runtime too as HttpCompileException.

Above is not the problem if referenced from within controller(s) or viewmodel(s) at same project.

Code example is given below (IdentityModel line number 2 in the code below gets underlined in red in design):

```
@using System.Security.Principal;
@using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims;

@model IPrincipal

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Claims";
    Layout = null;
}



@if (Model is IClaimsPrincipal)
{
    IClaimsIdentity identity = Model.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
    ...
```

Context is like below

- asp.net 4.0 MVC web application
- VS2010
- WIF 3.5

I added Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll assembly (installed WIF SDK in advance) to my asp.net mvc 4 web project.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install wif on your server (and your developer pc). Some people said that it can be binary deployed but in our project we could not do it

Comment: thanks for promptly answer: WIF SDK and WIF runtime installed as I wrote under context

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find the namespace, add it like this:

```
<add namespace="System.Security.Principal" />
<add namespace="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims" />
```

Find it in the web.config in your views folder.

i found another possible solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f7fbcd78-48a0-4877-af47-2f5a1af6cc14

> In order for Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll assembly to work you have to
>   make sure that target framework for your project is NOT .NET Framework
>   Client Profile.
>
> Project-> ProjectName Properties...
>
> Seems that VS2010 uses this Target Framework as default.

Another one here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/97cb3c15-9253-4ff1-a690-b203a65c0dfd

Rereferenced his dll and it worked. (not the original question - look further down)

Comment: I updated my answer - try and see if it helps. Seems there is a problem with the Microsoft.IdentityModel with the clientprofile.

Comment: I red about the one about Client Profile too. The clue is that ASP.NET MVC projects does not offer Client Profile option no matter what. So that one cannot address my issue

Comment: Too bad. Was my best guess. I wish you luck finding a solution.